# Security Scanner not finding assertion

Tags: security, security-scanner

I have been using the Salesforce Security Scanner to scan my code:

http://security.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner

Basically, the scan is telling me that I do not have any assert statements in my test class.  It does not make any sense because I have several... and have even added in some pointless ones for further testing.  Does anyone know why it might be showing up on the scanner?

```
@isTest
private class InactiveSalesRepControllerTest
{
    static testMethod void testInactiveLeadReassignment()
    {
        User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Department = 'Sales' AND UserRole.Name IN :Constants.REP_ROLES AND CompanyName = 'Equity Trust' AND IsActive = true AND Id != :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 2][1];
        List<Lead> testLeads = new List<Lead>();
        System.RunAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId()))
        {
            for(Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Lead l = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Test', OwnerId = u.Id);
                testLeads.add(l);
            }
            testLeads[2].Status = Constants.DORMANT_STATUS;
            insert testLeads;
            //testLeads[2].OwnerId = u.Id;
            //update testLeads[2];

            Task t = new Task(OwnerId = u.Id, Status = 'New', Subject = 'Test', WhoId = testLeads[0].Id);
            insert t;
        }

        u.IsActive = false;
        update u;

        Test.startTest();
        InactiveSalesRepController testMe = new InactiveSalesRepController();
        System.RunAs(new User(id = UserInfo.getUserId()))
        {
            testMe.findLeads();
            testMe.activeLeadsWithTasksReassign = 1;
            testMe.activeLeadsWithoutTasksReassign = 1;
            testMe.dormantLeadsReassign = 1;
            testMe.selectedActiveRep = testMe.activeSalesReps[0].getValue();
            testMe.assignLeads();
        }
        System.assert(true);
        Test.stopTest();

        //Had to remove the dormant parts because it is causing issues in production when we update the user after
        //updating the Lead (Mixed DML)
        List<Lead> leads = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :testLeads AND Status != :Constants.DORMANT_STATUS];
        for (Lead tLead: leads)
        {
            System.assertEquals(testMe.selectedActiveRep, tLead.OwnerId);
        }
        System.assert(2 == leads.size());

        //For some reason the security scanner kept saying that there were no asserts even though there are 2 above this... so I added this
        //to try to fix it.
        System.assert(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the culprit on my own.  I noticed that the `System.RunAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId()))` the previous developer used essentially does nothing at all.  I removed that as well as put asserts inside of the other `System.runAs` and outside of it as well, and it began working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see anything particularly wrong with your code above, your using a number of variations of System.assert vs System.assertEquals as well, so it's not as if it may favour one over the other for some reason. So all i can say is contact them via the Email contact option [here](http://security.force.com/security/contact/email).

Comment: Good plan.  Idk why I never think of contacting the companies directly...

Comment: Well... Update on this.  Contacting the company directly, and I never got a response.  There is actually an email division in Salesforce you can email directly about this sort of thing.  I got a single response directly back from them... that wasn't even close to answering my question.  It was a response that was given blaming **System.assert(true)**.  Basically ignoring the fact that I only added those in after it was already getting this issue with the valid asserts.

Comment: Sigh, not good, and sadly something i have also experienced all to often. I would recommend raising a Salesforce case and contacting your account manager (or Technical Account Manager  if you have one).

Comment: @dphil, Sorry that you did not feel you got adequate help via email. In that case, please book an office hour for live online help: http://security.force.com/security/contact/ohours